# should I add derivable features to a feature vector?

Tags: machine-learning

For supervised learning (like classification), is it a good idea to add new derivable features to a given feature set with the hope of improving accuracy?

For example:
- if "unit_price" and "no_of_units" are two given features, does it make sense to create a new feature "amount" (which is unit_price*no_of_units)? 
- if "standard_deviation" is a given feature, is it a good idea to create a new feature "variance" (which is standard_deviation^2)?

Is there a theoretical guideline for this, or is it just a matter of trial-and-error?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not a programming question, so I'd delete it and repost over at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO yes ,you can add new features like that..look at 'Kernel' in SVM where you can add feature xy if you have two features x and y.